# PySpark - Copy file to another location and delete folder

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, boto3

I have a `.txt` file on S3 in the following folder format:

`bucket/cust/customer_health_data/health_data.txt`

I want to copy and rename the .txt file to the following folder path `bucket/cust/datetime=20210530/new_file.txt` using `boto3`

Thus, a folder (`datetime=20210530`) needs to be created and the file copied to that new folder and the file renamed to 'new_file.txt'.

I tried searching the net a lot with `boto3` but didn't find any conclusive answers.

Please let me know if additional information is required.

Please anyone could help ?

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a move operation. You can achieve this by using the `copy_object` and `delete_object` methods of the s3 client in `boto3`.

```
src = {
    'Bucket': 'bucket',
    'Key': 'cust/customer_health_data/health_data.txt'
}

dst = {
    'Bucket': 'bucket', 
    'Key': 'cust/datetime=20210530/new_file.txt'
}

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Copy the object from source to destination
s3.copy_object(**dst, CopySource=src)

# Only use `delete_object` if you want to delete the original file
s3.delete_object(Bucket=src['Bucket'], Key=src['Key'])
```

Comment: thank you. Also is it possible to get the name of the source file (health_data.txt) dynamically from the path ? The name of the files keep changing, hence wanted a generic solution and the folder `datetime=yyyyMMddhhmmss` could also be generated dynamically ?

Comment: I would suggest asking a different question since this is the different requirement from the original post :-) nevertheless You can only get the matching files from the given S3 folder but for that you need to have some pattern that can match the desired filename. Does your source folder always contain a single file?

Comment: yes it will contain a single file only